# How can i use XMP to modify metadata of Sharepoint Document?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, xmp

I am trying to Modify Meta data of Sharepoint Document.
How can use XMP for this task?
Using C#.

Can anyone give me some code samples?

Answer (score 0):

[JPEG Data - Read Exif, XMP, and IPTC Data from a JPEG](http://jpegdata.codeplex.com/)

[BitmapTagger](http://bitmaptagger.codeplex.com/)

these can be used for image and xmp